# MongoDB - Subtracting Double in Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'll start with the part of the query that's not working right.

```
{$project: {"date":"$_id.date",
    "location":"$data.location",
    "coachgroup":"$data.coachgroup",
"staffedcoaches":"$data.staffedcoaches",
  "allots":{
    $cond: [
    {$eq: [
        "$data.coachgroup","Default"
        ]},
        {$floor: [
    {$subtract: 
    [NumberInt("$data.staffcoaches"),
    {$divide: 
        ["$data.virtualheads",
        "$data.ratio"
        ]}
        ]}
        ]},
        "$data.allots"
    ]}
   }
},
```

So, the "staffedcoaches" field is a Double. "virtualheads" and "ratio" are both Int32. "staffedcoaches" is derived from a count much earlier in the query. When I try to use it as-is in the subtraction, the result is null. When I try to use it with NumberInt() as shown below the staffedcoaches becomes a 0. Number() and NumberLong() are no more successful.

To take just one document as an example, the "ratio" is 15 and the staffedcoaches is 4. So the result should be 11. But I can only get a null or a -15.

Is there a way to get the Double treated as an Integer so I can complete this operation?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer. While the calculation wouldn't work in $project, it did work as an $addFields. (You may notice I took out the conditional. With or without it makes no difference. The only impacting factor was moving the calculations from $project to $addFields.)

```
{$project: {"date":"$_id.date",
"location":"$data.location",
"coachgroup":"$data.coachgroup",
"staffedcoaches":"$data.staffedcoaches"
},
{$addFields: {
"allots":{
    $floor:[
    {$subtract: 
        ["$staffedcoaches",
        {$divide:
            ["$virtualheads","$ratio"]}
    ]}]
        }}},
```